# Change theme of select menu placeholder in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to change the theme of select menu `placeholder` in jQuery mobile. I want different theme for `options` and different theme for the `placeholder`. But am unable to change it individually. The `data-theme` attribute is not working for options.

```
<option data-placeholder="true" data-theme="a">Heading</option>
<option>First</option>
<option>Second</option>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/saQFx/10/
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile this is done via optgroup.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Wgd66/

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="frontPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h3 id="heading">test</h3>          
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <select data-native-menu="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c">
            <optgroup label="Heading">
                <option value="first">First</option>
                <option value="second">Second</option>
            </optgroup>                    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I want to change the theme of label to "b" and rest all should be "data-theme= a". Is that possible somehow?